# Finding all modules $M$ over $\mathbb{C}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $M$ is a $\mathbb{C}[X]$-module. I am struggling with the following two questions:

1. Viewing $M$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, what are the possible modules $M$ such that the dimension of $M$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is $1$?
2. Viewing $M$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, what are the possible modules $M$ such that the dimension of $M$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is $2$?

In both cases, $M$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}[X]$ module. Using the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID we can conclude that:
\begin{equation*}
M\cong C[X]^n\oplus C[X]/(p_1(X))\oplus\cdots\oplus C[X]/(p_m(X))
\end{equation*}
where $p_1|p_2|\ldots|p_m$. And since $M$ is of finite dimension over $\mathbb{C}$ we must have $n=0$. Furthermore, the dimension of $M$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is

$$\sum_{j=1}^{m} \operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}\left(C[X]/(p_j(X))\right)$$

In the first case we have that

$$ M\cong C[X]/(p(X)),$$

and if $p(X)$ is linear then $M$ is just $\mathbb{C}$ which is of dimension $1$ over $\mathbb{C}$. What happens when $p(X)$ is not a linear polynomial?

EDIT: I have been able to determine what happens for some cases of the polynomial $p(X)$: If $p(X)$ is of degree $0$ then the quotient $\mathbb{C}[X]/(p(X))$ is just $0$ which is of $0$ dimension over $\mathbb{C}$. Also, if $p(X)$ has $k$ distinct roots then by the CRT we have that $\mathbb{C}[X]/(p(X)) ≅ \mathbb{C}^k$ which is of dimension $k$.

Comment: Keep in mind that $\mathbb{C}\left[X\right]/\left(p\left(X\right)\right)$ has dimension $\deg p$.

Comment: Why is it that the vector space $\mathbb{C}[X]/(p(X))$ has dimension deg p over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: A well-known fact you can find in most algebra texts. The main ingredient of the proof is that polynomials can be uniquely divided with remainder by $p\left(X\right)$, and the remainder will be a polynomial of degree $< \deg p$.

Comment: Can't seem to find it in my text book "Advanced modern algebra" though. Do you know anywhere online I can read about this proof?